# How to get Tweets using Twitterizer in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, twitterizer

I am using twitterizer2 to login twitter using Asp.net.I am able to login using twitterizer,but unable to get the tweets from my timeline which are tweeted by me and othres too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitterizer is not maintained anymore and **not compatible with Twitter API 1.1**.

Details about Twitter API 1.1: [blog](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/changes-coming-to-twitter-api)

---

From [Official page](https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer#what-am-i-supposed-to-do-now):

> **Will applications using Twitterizer stop working?**
>
> Not right away, no. I have no power to stop the code or binaries that
>   are already in use from working, nor would I want to. However, the
>   current version of Twitterizer uses version 1.0 of the Twitter API
>   which is scheduled for death in March 2013. At that time, I cannot
>   speak to any functionality.
>
> **What am I supposed to do now?**
>
> As I see it, you have three options: jump to a new library, make
>   Twitterizer your own, or roll your own.
>
> Twitterizer source code will remain available in its current state. I
>   encourage you to download the source and make it your own.
>
> If you'd rather not take that on, there are a couple of other
>   fantastic libraries. For example: Linq2Twitter and TweetSharp

---

As said above you need to find a new library compatible with Twitter API 1.1, as [Linq2Twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/) or [TweetSharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp).